# Isn't commutative property of $+$ in a ring obvious from other axioms?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ be a nonempty set and $+,.$ are binary compositions on $R$ such that (R,+,.) satisfies all the properties of a ring except the commutative property of $+.$ Then

$[(a+b)-(b+a)]=[(a+b)+(-b+(-a))]$ (using distributive law) =$[a+(b-b)+(-a)]=0.$

So $a+b=b+a,\forall~a,b\in R$

Thus we see that commutative property of $+$ is obvious from other axioms.

Why do we need still mention it in the definition of a ring separately?

Comment: How do you prove that $-(b+a)=(-b)+(-a)$?

Comment: ohk, I got it! I need unity in the ring.

Comment: Jave, careful there. Without commutativity you would have $-(b+a)=(-a)+(-b)$. Remember that in a group (swithcing to multiplicative notation as I predict you to have seen it written this way) $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$. I'm fairly sure this was Azif00's point.

Comment: See [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/702616/242)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94350/why-do-we-assume-ab-ba-in-a-ring-with-1-also-is-it-true-with-rings-without